# Add a filter before a request matching all HTTP methods but OPTIONS in Spring Security

Tags: filter, spring-security, http-method

In the security config, my method

```java
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
    httpSecurity
        .requestMatchers()
            .antMatchers("/users/**", "/activities/**").and()
        .addFilterBefore(authenticationTokenFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
}
```

adds a filter before the default `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter` provided by Spring Security. It is in a class extending `WebSecurityConfigurererAdapter` of course. All HTTP methods will be matched. **Can I exclude HTTP method OPTIONS from the match above?** Something like

```java
.and().ignoring().antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS)
```

I could duplicate the code and use `.antMatchers(HttpMethod.x)` for all the methods that should be matched, but it would create clutter.

Answer (score 0):

You can encapsulate your logic into a function that return a `Customizer<RequestMatcherConfigurer>` to reduce the duplicated codes, somethings like :

```java
private Customizer<RequestMatcherConfigurer> antMatchersExcludeHttpOptions(String... paths) {
        return c -> {
            for (HttpMethod method : EnumSet.allOf(HttpMethod.class)) {
                if (!method.equals(HttpMethod.OPTIONS)) {
                    c.antMatchers(method, paths);
                }
            }
        };
    }
```

And configure `HttpSecurity` as :

```java
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
    httpSecurity
        .requestMatchers(antMatchersExcludeHttpOptions("/users/**", "/activities/**"))
        .addFilterBefore(authenticationTokenFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
}
```